# Is it possible to connect to pcanywhere host?

Tags: vnc

Is there any way to connect to a pcanywhere host on a windows machine from Ubuntu 13.04? I would rather use a native linux program instead of installing pcanywhere on my machine with wine.

Answer (score 0):

pcanywhere claims to run on Linux, you may want to contact Symantec

> Offers heterogeneous host platform support across Windows® (now including Vista), Linux®, and Mac OS X®

http://us.norton.com/symantec-pcanywhere-host/

Or you can try open source alternates, I suggest FreeNX

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX